# Is it possible to attach a label to a line in the Google Drawings app?

Tags: google-drawings

Is there a way to attach a label to a line (straight or curved) in a Google drawing, so if the line is moved to a different location the label automatically goes with it?

I can place a textbox next to the line however there doesn't seen to be a way to keep them together. I tried using the group function but that doesn't keep the line and the textbox together physically.

Answer (score 4):

Copied from [Google product forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/8R027ius0mM):

> You can create a new shape in the middle of the two shapes you are
>   connecting and then connect the new shape to the original two shapes
>   with lines.   eg Shape 1  ----------  New Shape ---------- > Shape 2
>   Then add your text to the new shape and make the line and fill colour
>   transparent.

Comment: What? I don't understand your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could use Shift to select several objects and move them together. To maintain this association, group those objects, then be sure to select the group, not individual objects.

To be sure that you are selecting the group, instead of individual objects,

1. Click outside of the group, to cancel the active selection.
2. Click over one line or shape object, but no over a text object of that group.
3. The result should display a single square with handlers and group members will be highlighted but without object handlers.

[image: A group in Google Drawings]

**References**
[Select and manipulate multiple objects - Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/141907?hl=en)

Comment: Is it possible to anchor the text to the line?  The use case is when you have a flow chart where the line is anchored to two shapes.  When I move the shape, the line stays connected.  I always want the text to be the same place on the line.

Comment: You could add a textbox and connect one input and one output lines to the textbox. If this isn't clear please post a new question.

Comment: So looks like the answer is "not out of the box"

Answer (score 2):

[image: Two segments connected]

What if you just connected a "text" field between two segments?